# Singleton vs Dependency Injection

Tags: java, mvvm, dependency-injection, singleton

I never used by myself the java dependency injection feature, so I went reading some pages about it and I am still not clear about the duel between the singleton and dependency injection.

Let's take a basic example: Let's say I'm buidling a small Java application, using MVC or MVVM pattern. I would start with a login page, requesting a username and password.
Those 2 information may be needed later on in the application so I would need to store them in a simple POJO, accessible from any view of the application.

What should I use then? A singleton? Or should I @Inject the constructor of the POJO and get it when needed with the Injector (like done with Guice)?

Thanks for enlightening me :)

Comment: It's not either-or. 90% (99%?) of the time, it's both: Singletons with Dependency Injection.

Comment: @Andreas can you elaborate ?

Comment: I am a bit puzzled by Andreas' answer too to be frank :S

Comment: In Plain English: For a class how many instance you want to be created. If your anwser is that you want to restrict to only one. Then SingleTon Design pattern to the rescue.

Dependency Injection: In Plain English what kind of instance that you want to inject to your class properties. How that instance(can be either singleton/nonsingleton also) can be handled. you need to understand Association Aggregation and composition. Below is the link, Cheers

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/777540/Association-Aggregation-Composition-Dependency-and

Comment: As a note, don't try to invent security yourself; the example you gave is terribly insecure (you should discard a user's password as soon as possible). Entire frameworks, such as Spring Security or Shiro, exist to handle all of this for you already. In the case of Spring Security, information about the logged-in user (but not the password) is available to both controllers and views via out-of-the-box integrations.

Comment: I interpreted @Andreas' comment as saying that you frequently inject an instance into many places, but it just so happens that it's the same instance. Or rather, it's irrelevant whether it is a singleton or not.

Comment: Thanks for the information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would stay away from a POJO getting injected with a dependency. In this situation, I'd have my ViewModels injected with a singleton-type service that provides/manages your user. If they need the current user, their injected service provides them with the current relevant POJO instance. So long as your user management service is wrapped in an interface, thus can be replaced later without destroying functionality, I think this satisfies IoC.

This is how I've approached similar problems, I'm not sure it is the best way of doing it though.

Comment: I do understand the point and indeed going through a dedicated service to access the information in the way to go for sure.
So if we have a service, we inject the service implementation where needed and this one will fetch the user data from this POJO (or whatever else). But how do you make this POJO "persistent" (not physically, but keeping it available in the application memory). A basic static instance in the service implementation? Something more neat?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question exactly, but the service instance is a 'singleton' in that only one instance gets injected, so no need for static. Just a single "Current User" instance in the single service instance. As the service is shared/singleton - all requests will get passed the same POJO from that same service instance.

Comment: Reading again what I wrote, I feel a bit stupid. I guess I need some rest! Thanks for trying to reply to the stupid quertion though :)

Answer (score 2):

Simple POJO should not be injected through Dependency-injection.
It either should not be singleton, since you need to create a new instance for each request.

Dependency-injection should used to do the 'wiring' of your application components/services/repositories/beans/etc. It helps you to make your application modularity, encapsulation between your components. And much more..

Singleton is when you need some Object to be only 1 instance per application. It can be achieved programmatically with static instance and getInstance method (like singleton pattern), or by creating only 1 instance in the Main class or in the context. In Spring, unless configured else, all beans will be singleton, because the context will create only 1 instance.

The dependency-injection will become handy when you need to wire your 'singletons' with each other.

Hope it was clarified enough.